# Ho to get item values in ItemsControl in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, wpf

[image]I want to get the item values from ItemsControl  when click the ItemsControl item .

Below is my sample code:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="ListViewProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Product}"  PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="listView_Click" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Border Margin="10" Width="110" Height="160">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <Border Width="100" Height="100" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
                                            <Border.Effect>
                                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                            </Border.Effect>
                                            <Border.Background>
                                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding Image}" />
                                            </Border.Background>
                                        </Border>
                                        <!--<TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:C}}" FontSize="17" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium"/>-->
                                        <TextBlock Margin="5 0" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapPanel/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Code- behind:

```
private void listView_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (sender as ItemsControl);

        if (item != null)
        {

        }


    }
```

but this is not working, i am nt getting the items details. Please help me on this.

I need to use Itemcontrol only. when I use listview it showing  the list is not a proper way, so I have use itemscontrol. please see the below images. when I  use list view it shows like a box. please find the screenshots.

[image]

Comment: Why not use a ListView or ListBox and bind the SelectedItem ?

Comment: @NawedNabiZada but listview it showing as a box. please find the above image.

Comment: @kartheekij i would also suggest to use `ListBox` instead of `ItemsControl`. You can workout on the `Style` for `ListBox` to look like what you expecting with `ItemsControl`.

Comment: The button will be e.originalsource .  If I follow what you've done correctly, the listview will be sender.

Comment: If you insist on using an `ItemsControl` you could make the datatemplate be a button with an onclick. You can bind the item that is clicked. Or try to retrieve it via the sender.

Comment: @fstam var item = (sender as ItemsControl)

        if (item != null)
        {

        }

this code not working. item  value is null.

Comment: "make the datatemplate be a button with an onclick"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of handling the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` of the `ItemsControl`, you could define an `ItemContainerStyle` and handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the container. You could then simply cast the `DataContext` of the `sender` argument to your type:

```
private void ContentControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var product = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext as Product;
    ...
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ListViewProducts" ItemsSource="{Binding Product}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ContentControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        ...
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Or handle the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event for the `Border` in the `ItemTemplate` and do the same thing.